# how to exclude pattern from expressJS route

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to configure expressJS routes.

```
app.route(base + '/inventory/adjustments').get(policy.isAllowed, inventoryChangeCtrl.search);


  app.route(base + '/inventory/:inventoryId(?!^adjustments$)').get(policy.isAllowed, inventoryCtrl.findById)
```

Consider input `../inventory/adjustments`

The problem is that in the first route, it matches properly, but the controller calls `next()` which is supposed to fall through to a `default route handler` that I setup elsewhere. But instead the next route handler is also matched.

So now I'm trying to exclude the more specific strings from that route handler using a regex, but now it's not matching correct input like `.../inventory/9039309309`.

Can anyone suggest how to exclude the first route from the second route? (and still allow next to be called for the default handler).

Thanks.

Comment: are you saying that a get to /inventory/adjustments is also been matched to /inventory/:inventory_id

Comment: Use redirect instead of calling next.

Comment: yes @Dave Briand  the second route is also matching the first request because I call next(). If the first controller returns a response it's not called of course, but there's a default middleware that all my responses are supposed to pass through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `inventoryId` is always numerical, you can make the match more specific:

```
app.route(base + '/inventory/:inventoryId(\\d+)', ...);
```

That way, it won't match `"adjustments"` and the route won't trigger.

The same would apply for other specific patterns that it may match, as long as that pattern doesn't also match `"adjustments"`.

**EDIT**: if `inventoryId` is a MongoDB `ObjectId`, the match would become:

```
app.route(base + '/inventory/:inventoryId([a-fA-F\\d]{24})', ...);
```

Comment: inventoryId is a hex string - it's a mongodb id to be exact (which I think is hex). But I'll try this positive match approach and see if it works better than trying to exclude the string.

Comment: @RichardG I've edited my answer to show how you can match `ObjectId`'s